# What package to use to write a letter?

Tags: letters

I would like to write a letter to someone. So far I've discovered two packages `letter` and `lettre` (written by a french guy). Both are nice, but I would like to customize the layout of the letter.

For instance, I would like to move the date below the address and move the address to fit my windowed envelope.

I spent some time trying to achieve this, unfortunately these packages seems not very modular. So I am thinking to rewrite a very simple package where each letter component (address, date, ...) are using `textblock`

```
\begin{textblock}{hwidthi}[hhx i,hhyi](hx i,hyi)
...
\end{textblock}
```

What would be the most straightforward solution in my case?

Comment: The date is above the address in `lettre` because it's the traditional layout out of letters in French.

Comment: It is, but the envelopes I bought have a window located slightly above.

Comment: I found [scrlttr2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2?lang=en) a very convenient package.

Comment: You can easily customise the layout  of the lettre heading: it is a `picture` environment, with a number of `\parbox`es. The default placement and dimensions of these boxes is explained in § 2.7.3 (De l'entête), pp 25-26 of the documentation.

Comment: `letter`, `scrlttr2`, `newlfm` and `isodoc` are all discussed in [Correspondence](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/correspondence.shtml) if that's of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps - here's the code of my personal standard letter using the [scrlttr2](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2) document class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrlttr2}

% Options
% true/on/yes oder false/off/no
\KOMAoptions{
    parskip=half,   
    fromphone=off,  
    fromrule=off,   
    fromfax=off,    
    fromemail=off,  
    fromurl=off,        
    addrfield=on,   
    foldmarks=true, 
    backaddress=on  
}

% Standard packages
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Additional packages
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[]{url}

% Some sombols - just in case :)
\usepackage{textcomp}

%% Setting the Variables
\setkomavar{fromname}{Dr.~Manuel Kuehner}
\setkomavar{signature}{\small\sffamily Dr.~Manuel Kuehner}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{SomeStreet 2\\ 71706 SomeTown}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0123-123456789 (Mobil)}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{xxx@gmail.com}
\setkomavar{fromurl}{www.manuelkuehner.de}
\setkomavar{frombank}
{%
    Konto 000\,000\,000,
    Postbank Berlin,
    BLZ 100\,100\,10\\
    IBAN DE\,08\,10010010\,123456789, BIC PBNKDEFF
}

% Footnote with bank account, custom code
\setkomavar{firstfoot}
{%
    \parbox[b]{\linewidth}
    {%
        \centering\usekomavar{frombank}%
    }%
}


% Letter specific information
% Leave the {} empty and it will not appear.
\setkomavar{customer}{}
\setkomavar{subject}{Cancellation}
\setkomavar{myref}{--}
\setkomavar{yourmail}{}
\setkomavar{yourref}{}
\setkomavar{invoice}{}

\setkomavar{date}{\today} % Date of letter

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}
{% Adressaten
Name Name\\
Street Street\\
Town Town
}

\opening{Dear Mr. Mueller,}

\enlargethispage{0\baselineskip}

I would like to cancel my newspaper.

\closing{Best regards}
\ps{}
\encl{Attached documents} % comment out if not needed
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result of the code above:

[image]

> But I must admit that it took me a while until I figured out how the
>   document class works and until I was satisfied with the result. But I
>   use it for years now without changing the code.

Comment: Seems the space between `Dr.` and `M` is too large (`frenchspacing`). Try `Dr.~M` in all matching occasions.

Comment: @Johannes_B Or `Dr.\ M`

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thx for the hint!

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for the hint (sorry, that was years ago but I missed it apparently that time)!

Comment: You're welcome!